# Why Scala's compiler is not able to use an implicit conversion of an inherited type?

Tags: scala, inheritance, implicits

I am currently digging in the implicit topic, and got myself stuck with this case :

```
class A
class B extends A

object A { implicit def b2String(b: B): String = "B" }
object B { implicit def a2String(a: A): String = "A" }

val s: String = new B // This does not compile
```

I know this is a bit of an edge case, but I wanted to understand it. Shouldn't the compiler pick A's implicit (b2String) ? Or does (as it seems) it stuck to the most specific type's companion object (B) ? Does that mean inherited type's companion object implicits are not inherited ?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT** : 
If A's companion object is deleted, then it compiles and the value of s is "A". So the compiler is able to figure out than an implicit valid for A is also valid for B.

**EDIT** :
If I do the following changes, this also compiles :

```
  class A
  class B extends A

  object A { implicit def b2String(b: B): Int = 1 }
  object B { implicit def a2String(a: A): String = "A" }

  val s: String = new B
  val i: Int = new B
```

So companion objects implicits are inherited.

Comment: The error message from the compiler clearly explains the problem!  "
- type mismatch;  found   : caseclass.caseclass2.B  required: String Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:  both method b2String in object A of type (b: caseclass.caseclass2.B)String  and method a2String in object B of type (a: caseclass.caseclass2.A)String  are possible conversion functions from caseclass.caseclass2.B to String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't compile because there are two available implicits, and by rules in http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#overloading-resolution, they have equal relative weight: `b2String` gets 1 over `a2String` because it's in the companion object of the derived class, and `a2String` gets 1 over `b2String` because it's more specific.

Comment: This could be useful for a Scala quiz :) Thank for your help.